# help me with priority stack in C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a stack which will have the following methods:

```
getValueOf ("key")
getKeyOf ("value")
addKeyAndValue ("key" "value")
delete ("key")
```

can anyone please help me as I am very new to C sharp

Answer (score 3):

You need to check [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eayzh46.aspx) class or if you want as you said "priority" (sorted) you need to check [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) Class.

**EDIT :** If you need to implement the stack by your own. You need to check [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx), [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) and [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) interfaces.

However better to use already exiting classes in Framework if they fit your needs. And based on your description seems you need `Dictionary` or `SortedList`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at the [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class?
That's no stack, but the methods you describe are not typical for a stack, either.

*getValueOf( "key" )*:

```
var value = dictionary[key];
```

*addKeyAndValue( "key" "value" )*:

```
dictionary.Add( key, value );
```

*delete( "key" )*

```
dictionary.Remove( key );
```

*getKeyOf ("value")* with linq:

```
var key = dictionary.Where( pair => pair.Value == 10 )
                    .Select( pair => pair.Key ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need a stack? What you are describing sounds very much like a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) collection.

A stack is a very specific data structure and would not normally allow you to search by keys of values - it is a "first in last out" data structure that would not have the methods you want.

A dictionary on the other hand has these search capabilities and has methods on it that are pretty close to what you are describing.

Comment: yeah this is one of my hw questions which had asked me to implement such stack please help me I'm ruined as I got no idea

Comment: @ghostantanieh - You can wrap your class around a dictionary, but without knowing more about the constraints you have (are you allowed to use existing collection types? What are you not allowed to do?) it is difficult to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a stack class in C#,  Here is a quick guide to using it:

http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=65

Hope that helps.